# AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer acts out of the box in my story!

Tags: bug, design, developer-story

I've added one of my answers to my developer [story](https://stackoverflow.com/story/ali-dehghani) and apparently, `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer` is not gonna reside inside the box:

[image]

*<sup>Just a typically long Spring name!</sup>*

I was wondering is there a way to handle this freakishly long words in the developer story?

Comment: Ahh, good old Spring class name. You can see them a mile away :D.

Comment: [`word-break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break) :)

Comment: @Tunaki :D And still it's not longest one!